# How do I force a validation summary to appear with FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I've got FluentValidation set up in my ASP.Net MVC 3 project. I have a form which has two inputs. Either can be blank, but not both.

Here's what I have:

```
RuleFor(x => x.username)
    .NotEmpty()
    .When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.email) == true)
    .WithMessage("Please enter either a username or email address")
```

This correctly puts the error directly above my username field. However, when both fields are left blank I'd prefer the Validation Summary to show the message

Is there a way to do this? I've been thinking I could create an unused field in the model and put the error on that (if the other two are blank),

```
RuleFor(x => x.unused_field)
    .NotEmpty()
    .When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.email) == true && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.username) == true)
    .WithMessage("Please enter either a username or email address")
```

but this feels like an awkward way to do it. Is there a way I can just add a message to the validation summary?

Comment: Never tried, just an idea: `RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.username))...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reference I could find was [this](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/259221).

Now if your model is that simple and this rule is the only one then this rule should be enough:

```
RuleFor(x => x)
        .Must(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Email) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.UserName))
        .WithName(".") // This adds error message to MVC validation summary
        .WithMessage("Please enter either a username or email address");
```

Just add `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to your view and you're good to go.

But if you're going to put more rules on your model then to my knowledge there is only one 'hacky' way I could think of:
in your controller action add this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (ModelState["."].Errors.Any())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ModelState["."].Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This will add first error message from `"."` property to model property (adapt it to your needs). Also you will have to do a `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` to show only model level errors in validation summary.

Third option: add rule(s) to `unused_property` and use `@Html.ValidationSummaryFor(x => x.unused_property)` as a validation summary

Comment: Why will the first option work with only one rule? Shouldn't I be able to add more rules after that without affecting it?

Comment: Because in first option you have `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which shows **all** the errors you have including property specific ones

Comment: I don't mind the validation summary showing up when I have _other_ validation errors. I just don't want the individual ones showing when both are empty.

Comment: So? Neither of the solutions I provided work for you? What is wrong with the second one?

Comment: I wasn't complaining Ramunas, just saying the first one will work fine for me. I have accepted your answer

Comment: This didn't work for me, the ModelState did not get populated with the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue can be solved with FluentValidation [AbstractValidator.Custom](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#AbstractValidatorCustom):

```
Custom(m => String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Username) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Email)
    ? new ValidationFailure("", "Enter either a username or email address.")
    : null);
```

Empty string in ValidationFailure constructor assures validation message is not bound to any input field so it appears in validation summary like

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Enter either a username or email address.")
```

would.

Comment: This didn't work for me, the validation message didn't appear in the model state. The Custom method also appears to be obsolete. I tried using RuleFor(x => x).Custom but the signature didn't match up with your code.